# How to better design pre sale and sale staged smart contracts

Tags: ico, presale

I am planning to create a stage based smart contract, like a pre-sale contract and then first and second stage of sales. What is best idea to do? Shall we create everything in one contract or multiple contracts for each stage would be a good practice.

If some one provide a code sample link, I'd appreciate that.

Many Thanks,

Comment: There are available open source contracts here: https://github.com/tokenmarketnet/ico